# How to change --primary-color variable in polymer if one is loading components through PolyGit

Tags: polymer, web-component, polygit

I'm using polygit to load the polymer components. Is there any way I can override --primary-color without any CSS hacks?

This is the way I'm loading polymer....

```
<base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+v1.4/components/">
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your custom element

```
:host{
  --primary-color:blue;
}
```

Or you if you are doing it in HTML then use `custom-style` and update the value in `:root` to apply it everywhere, or inside element to apply it on a particular element

Apply it to all the elements

```
<style is="custom-style">
  :root{
     --primary-color:blue;
  }
```

Apply it to single element

```
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-card{
     --primary-color:blue;
  }
```

Alternately if you are designing an app i'll recommend to create `app-theme.html` which will be your central repository for your application theme and import the `app-theme` using `link` tag.

Please read polymer's [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling) for more details on styling or check out this [polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omASiF85JzI)

Comment: I don't have any custom elements at all.

Comment: Okay I got the hint. What I can do is import style like this.

    <style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>

And I can declare that in <style is="custom-style"></style>.
Then I can declare that variable in :root instead of declaring in :host.

Comment: Yes if you are going to use it in HTML then `custom-style` is required but you don't need `shared-style` for this. I'll update my answer